Any criteria for flagging “no longer needed” for comments?
Generally, I think stackexchange sites treat comments as a sticky notes, which is better to be removed if it can be.  Reference:  How do comments work?
I’m asking this question because I came encountered a comment which I think is “no longer needed” but such flag was declined.  Namely, this comment: How do Bitcoin clients find each other?
A comment to indicate the comment-poster is also curious, can be substituted by an action of upvote for the question.  If so, I thought such comments are almost always “no longer needed”.
… Or am I missing any view points..?

Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

I agree with both of you that unnecessary comments should be removed, but would actually rather encourage that people continue to flag such unnecessary comments, even if there is only a single one of them. 
Unnecessary comments add visual clutter and cost visitors time to find what they're actually looking for. Globally seen, it is the vastly preferable outcome that such comments are flagged and removed quicker, rather than not reported and removed later.

I agree, comments can and should usually be removed if they don't add anything useful to the question or answer. In the case you linked, I removed the comment because I agree it doesn't add any value. In general though it is probably not worth reporting comments unless there are a lot of them on one post or they contain insulting/inappropriate language :)
